# server defragment tool

Tags: windows, web-server

what's the best defrag tool for a web / database server running windows 2008 server?

will regular defrag improve performance? what are your experiences

thanks

Comment: How do you propose to account for an X hour (lets say... 24) server outage, in order to save a few nanoseconds here and there?

Answer (score 5):

Fragmentation can be a lot more severe than "a few nanoseconds here and there". I deal with files that are sitting in hundreds of thousands of fragments on a weekly basis.

For single-file defragmentation, nothing beats the command-line tool **Contig** from [SysInternals](http://www.sysinternals.com) (free download). It can be used to defrag folders as well.

For full drive defragmentation, I use [**Defraggler**](http://www.defraggler.com), which is free (and you can opt out of the Yahoo! Toolbar during installation). It allows scheduling, which means you can set up an unattended defrag during off-peak times, a Quick Defrag (which is configurable), plus a command-line version.

Answer (score 1):

Under certain circumstances, it is possible that defragmentation could help.  If your server automatically creates large numbers of files, or you have rapid incremental growth of a database on the box, or are otherwise doing a large number of file writes, defragmentation can help.  For the low-intensity writes commonly seen (ftp uploads, log files, etc.) you might just schedule something infrequent during low-use times.

I don't have experience with Server 2008, but on 2k3, we used [DisKeper Server](http://www.diskeeper.com/Diskeeper/standard/standard.aspx) for an application that wrote large numbers of PDFs to disk.  It worked really well for us.  We also used it to minimize fragmentation caused by database backups on a separate server.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly what and how performance will be affected is dependent on the user of the server.  For example, if you have 100+ users accessing the same file server at more or less the same time, you could have a heavily fragmented server that has no perceptible performance issue under most circumstances - especially when using small files.  If you routinely store files that are 100's of MB in size then this could have a significant performance impact, especially if you copy those files locally for what ever reason.  Another thing that defragging can help with is backups - an appropriately defragged system can result in faster overall reads when the backup system is performing its backup.

I agree with Diskeeper Server use - though there are other products that can be used.